# Showing that a function $G : [0,1) \times [0,1) \rightarrow [0,1)$ is not a surjection

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

While proving $|\Bbb C|=|\Bbb R|$ in Just and Weese's Set Theory book, they construct a function $G : [0,1) \times [0,1) \rightarrow [0,1)$ where $\langle x,y\rangle \in [0,1) \times [0,1)$ such that $x = +.x_0x_1x_2...$ and $y=+.y_0y_1y_2...$ and $G(x,y) = +.x_0y_0x_1y_1x_2y_2...$

It is clear to me why this function is one-to-one, however he makes the comment that it does not map $[0,1) \times [0,1)$ onto $[0,1)$. But since each digit of $z\in G$ is free to be any number 0 through 9 without restriction, I am led to the conclusion that G is onto. My guess at a solution would be to create some function that alters $z$ in such a way that it cannot be written as $+.x_0y_0x_1y_1x_2y_2...$  however I cannot find such a function.

Comment: It’s onto, but it’s not one-to-one without some tinkering, because some rationals have two decimal expansions, e.g., $\frac12=0.5000\dots=0.4999\dots$.

Comment: To paraphrase, he solves the issue you mention by saying that we just discard those extra expansions. Now I am truly confused since it is an exercise in the book to show why it is not onto and I have written the function verbatim.

Comment: If they discard either the all-zeroes or the all-nines expansions, then $0.090909\dots$ is not in the range of $G$.

Comment: Ah that's clever, I knew it had something to do with non-unique decimal expansions. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure! (It’s a cute little problem.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must first fix some convention as to what do you do with numbers admitting two different decimal representations, otherwise the functions $G$ is not defined. Whatever choice you make, consider $x=0.1919191919191919191919....$. It can't be in the image of the function $G$ since the only way to interleave two decimal representations to obtain $x$ is by $G(0.11111....,0.99999.....)$. However, that pair is not in the domain of the function.